# Calculate $p$ given a parabola and the equation of a tangent

Tags: calculus

Given that the line

$3x + y -1 = 0$

is tangent to the parabola with equation

$y = -2x^2 +px + (1-p)$

EDIT: P > 3
EDIT 2: Fixed equation of tanget

I have to find $p$. I have tried making them equal to find a common point but that didn't turn out anything useful, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've edited my answer after you've fixed the equation of your tangent (Edit 2). Apparently, there does not exist a real solution for $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The line and the parabola have to meet at a single point, hence the discriminant of the second-degree polynomial 
$$ -2x^2+px+(1-p)-(3x-1) = -2x^2 + (p-3) x + (2-p) $$
has to be zero. That implies $(p-3)^2+8(2-p)=0$ and $p=\color{red}{7\pm2\sqrt{6}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you substitute the linear equation ($y=3x-1$) into the parabola you get $$2x^2+(3-p)x+(p-2)=0.$$So now you have a quadratic equation that can only have one zero, since the line is tangent to the parabola. What does this tell you about the discriminant?

Answer (score 0):

**This is after you've corrected the equation of your tangent (Edit 2):**

Well we can substitute the equation of the parabola into the equation of the tangent to give:
$$3x-2x^2+px+(1-p)-1=0$$
$$-2x^2+(p+3)x-p=0$$
Note that the discriminant $\Delta$ for a repeated root must equal zero.
Therefore, you must set the discrimant equal to zero, and solve for $p$.
$$\Delta=(p+3)^2-4\cdot2\cdot p=0$$
The solutions of $p$ are complex, indicating **there does not exist** a real value of $p$ such that the line is tangent to the parabola.

Try varying $p$ using the slider with [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b9vlugywdx), and you will see what I mean.